# How can I improve lag between filebeat > redis < logstash > elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash, filebeat

I have a relatively low frequency log file (1 per second), I simply read from filebeat, push to external redis (net latenct ~5ms), on the same server as redis I pull via logstash and push to elasticsearch.

Nothing is really being overloaded CPU-wise but I still see a delay of ~4-10 seconds. How can I minimize that and make it nearly real-time?

**Filebeat to Redis** uses `list` with `bulk_max_size: 0` and `flush.timeout: 0s`

**Logstash** uses 4 threads.

Comment: Please provide details of the logstash input configuration. Are you using path or host/port, channels or lists etc.

Comment: Also the filebeat configuration. Software versions? That determines whether you have a registry file or registry directory. How big is the registry and how often is it flushed (filebeat.registry.flush)?

Comment: filebeat 8.12.2, filebeat.registry.flush is default